# Return response.body in a http request

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm trying to return response value and use it. But my callback function doesn't work properly. Please review the code and help me. I tried so many things. I read articles, stackoverflow questions/answers about callback functions. None of 'em work in my situation. If you know how can I solve it, please help me, Thanks in advance

```
function createDynamicLink(callback){
   .
   .
   .
   .

  request({
    url: dynamicLinksApi,
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: body,
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    callback(response.body.shortLink);
  });
}

var dynamicLink = createDynamicLink(function (returnValue){
  console.log(returnValue) // <----- this works
  return returnValue; // I return it so the returnValue assign 'dynamicLink' variable 
}); 
console.log(dynamicLink)  // <----- But it won't assign. it says 'undefined'
```

Comment: Returning a value from the callback does not return a value to your `dynamicLink` variable because that callback happens long after that function has moved on.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: There is no solution. You can't do that. Find another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: thanks for your response. time to plan z

Comment: Effectively, work with your "This works" line. Code that needs the result, must go where the result exists.